В чем проблема при авторизация на сайте hh.ru с помощью библиотеки requests?
У меня есть код на Python, который авторизируется на сайта hh.ru через логин и пароль:
import requests

url = 'https://moscow.hh.ru/account/login'

user_agent_val = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url, headers = {
    'User-Agent': user_agent_val
})

session.headers.update({'Referer':url})

session.headers.update({'User-Agent':user_agent_val})

_xsrf = session.cookies.get('_xsrf', domain=".hh.ru")
print(_xsrf)

post_request = session.post(url, {
     'backUrl': 'https://moscow.hh.ru/',
     'username': '***',
     'password': '***',
     '_xsrf':_xsrf,
     'remember':'yes',
})

with open("hh_success.html","w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(post_request.text)

Вывод:
{"recaptcha":{"isBot":false,"siteKey":"6Ld7XBgTAAAAABhqMs0avEPpilCq3w8FsocJLK_n"},"hhcaptcha":{"isBot":true,"captchaState":"xO_d5SW_cskz_QckOb5AYevg21xzSxIi2thEEmOn8iC5j2IzZ_tER3IN063AXf2WWoPY8xmDTdZcPmuaT-Orb7bDQR-V6WxJ-1zy6hprnH7iCfxYm_LvwKCDyDu-Sl-xe1KSTpnmVHyEczbUobsf5SLZWAWUO_YwWbeoE6_fv7HbcxlBUneAIQM70WehnGHIX2xt5FcsK-Nb0ufhhpiGv4pA6FIX7mHYOLQRCBrMwC3shYWLl6iKFQLDSdoRCktvo-snjRDILtbx2nxiR11uLua5B-ilNwPiUeMs0WaJnugbqnXM80ElSDxuo8-JFzFKrjWsWW-WC4st-dtBTBkFz87CE7SN9D-5Rje2h35V0oj-q3O28uAouSTBJE-x1upTFRExuS8dmaqeGT9rmC4C3g==","captchaError":false}}

Предполагаю, что проблема в капче, которая запрашивается на сайте. Есть ли способ ее обойти, используя библиотеку requests? Заранее спасибо!

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?

Капчи для того и сделаны, чтобы защищать от роботов. Если нужно спарсить данные - нужно использовать API сайта.
